# Set column value to different randomly chosen values from another table

Tags: oracle, database-design, plsql

My goal: Set PID_FM in every row to a randomly picked value out of all the values matched by the subquery.

However the FM_ID is only picked once, and therefore the whole column has the same value. I would want it to be different for every row. How can I achieve this? I am working with PL/SQL (ORACLE)

```
UPDATE Distribution
SET PID_FM = 
(SELECT *
 FROM(SELECT *
        FROM ( 
        SELECT Fm_Id FROM FAMILIES_IN_NEED 
        UNION 
        SELECT PID FROM HELPED_FAMILY
    ) T
      ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value)
      WHERE rownum=1 AND pid_fm is not NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any details regarding your distribution table, so I've made up my own test case ([db<>fiddle is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mhLYAVq8)).

Given a table, `distribution`, with col1 as the primary key:

```
create table distribution
as
select level *2 col1, cast(null as integer) col2
from   dual
connect by level <= 10;

alter table distribution add constraint dist_pk primary key (col1);
```

and a table, `nums`, containing a list of ids:

```
create table nums as
select level * 3 id
from   dual
connect by level <= 20;
```

You'd want to first assign a row number to each data set and then use that to join the two sets together, and then you can update the rows in the `distribution` table.

Given the complexity of your requirement, a `merge` statement is (IMO) easier to understand than the corresponding `update` statement would be, as it reduces the need to have the subquery twice.

E.g.:

```
merge into distribution tgt
  using (select d.col1,
                n.id
         from   (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn from distribution) d
                inner join (select id, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) rn from nums) n
                on d.rn = n.rn) src
  on (tgt.col1 = src.col1)
when matched then
  update set tgt.col2 = src.id;
```